# Tools to inspect an ethernet packet travels through host's interfaces?

Tags: networking, local-area-network, ethernet, packet

I am debugging a local ethernet connection on a Linux machine. I want to inspect the ethernet packets as they travel. in and out current machines' interfaces. I do not have a GUI on the machine. Is there tool to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As luck would have it, there are indeed tools to do such a thing:

- [Microsoft Network Monitor for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4865)
- [WireShark for Windows and *NIX](http://www.wireshark.org/) (It also has a [command line interface](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html))
- [TCPDump for anything that plugs into a wall.](http://www.tcpdump.org/)

Comment: I am using Linux over a command line, WireShark as a GUI tool doesn't seem to meet the requirement.

Comment: @yangchenyun updated my post. Wireshark will still work and so will tcpdump.

Comment: ...and you can still run it on a remote GUI display, and you can import tcpdump files....